# Gridview Show and Hide a Specific Column

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview in which a specific column `Date`. I have set the `Visible` property of column to false because I want to show on different conditions of page. Please tell me how can I do it using vb.net that my `Date` column should show or hide at runtime

**Update**

My current code is

```
   If Not Page.User.Identity.Name = "bilal" Then
            GridView1.AutoGenerateEditButton = False

            GridView2.AutoGenerateEditButton = False
            GridView3.AutoGenerateEditButton = False
        Else
            GridView1.AutoGenerateEditButton = True
            GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True

            GridView1.DataBind()
            If GridView1.Columns.Count > 0 Then
                'assuming your date-column is the first '
                GridView1.Columns(3).Visible = True
            Else
                GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(0).Visible = False
                For Each gvr As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
                    gvr.Cells(0).Visible = True
                Next
            End If



            GridView2.AutoGenerateEditButton = True
            GridView3.AutoGenerateEditButton = True

        End If
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you've set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `True`, the Column-Count will be 0, then you need to loop the rows and show/hide the appropriate cells. Otherwise you can use the `Visible` property.

```
GridView1.DataBind()
If GridView1.Columns.Count > 0 Then
    'assuming your date-column is the 4.'
    GridView1.Columns(3).Visible = True
Else
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(3).Visible = False
    For Each gvr As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        gvr.Cells(3).Visible = True
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Yes it works with autogenertae columns but it shows the all coulmns in gridview and i want to show only one column to show or hide .I have updated my current code to my question please give me further suggestion

Comment: Edited my answer to provide the correct column index(3). You've only changed it to 3 partially.

Comment: So Now What should i do for a specific coloumn